# Convert month (date) into full month (string)

Tags: spss

I have a date field (adate10) called Period with values like 07/02/2018.

I need to convert this into a string like "July 2, 2018."

I can use the code below to produce a string, Period_String, that says "JUL 2, 2018." I can't figure out how to format the month as the full month, e.g., "July." Is the only option to create an if/then statement that says 'if 1 then "January", if 2, then "February"', etc.? Was hoping there was a built in format but can't find it.

```
* extract each date element, then format.
compute mo = xdate.month(Period).
compute da = xdate.mday(Period).
compute yr = xdate.year(Period).

formats mo (month) da yr (F4.0).
execute.

* concatentate date elements as strings.
string Period_String (a30).
compute Period_String = concat(ltrim(string(mo,month)), " ", ltrim(string(da,F4)), ", ", ltrim(string(yr,F4))).
execute.
```

Answer (score 1):

see the revised month format (`month9` instead of `month`):

```
compute Period_String = concat(ltrim(string(mo,month9)), " ", ltrim(string(da,F4)), ", ", ltrim(string(yr,F4))).
```

**EDIT**:
using @mirirai's one-liner suggestion + getting only first letter in capitals:

```
string Period_String(a20).
COMPUTE Period_String = CONCAT(
            RTRIM(char.substr(STRING(period,MONTH9),1,1)),
            RTRIM(lower(char.substr(STRING(period,MONTH9),2)))," ",
            LTRIM(STRING(XDATE.MDAY(Period),F2)), ", ", 
            LTRIM(STRING(XDATE.YEAR(period),F4))
            ).
```

Comment: Actually there is no need to create day, month and year variable in the first place. You can also convert the date on the fly, which results in this oneliner: `COMPUTE Period_String =  CONCAT(RTRIM(STRING(period,MONTH9)), " ", LTRIM(STRING(XDATE.MDAY(Period),F2)), ", ", LTRIM(STRING(XDATE.YEAR(period),F4))).`

Comment: Both options get me very close but the `month9` argument returns the month in all caps, whereas I need it in normal caps (e.g., "July ..." instead of "JULY". Is the only option to extract all but the first letter of each month, make them lower case (with lower function), and then reassemble the string? If so, might be easier to simply go with the `if mo = 1 mo2 = "January". if mo = 2 mo2 = "February". etc`.

Comment: It was close but not completely solved due to the month9 argument returning the month in all caps. I went with a more cumbersome route of extracting the month with `compute mo = xdate.month(Period)` and then converting it via `string(mo2(a10). execute. if mo = 1 mo2 = "January".` etc. for the remaining months.

Comment: So you didn't try my edited version - I took care of the first capital letter only problem...